# JPEG to AI converted image ungrouping

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I made a hand sketch on paper (just pencil sketch no colors), took picture, used a web based converter to convert JPEG to AI.
   I want to add color to different parts in adobe illustrator but ungroup option is grayed out.
Can anyone tell how to ungroup an image converted to vector through a web based converter?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the vectors after expanding, the image is not grouped, it is a **Compound Path**,

go to menu **Object** > **Compound Path** > **Release**

Or press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> Mac / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> Win

Then you can **Ungroup**

Comment: Doing this converts all my drawing into black.

Comment: Yes, but you have all the vectors to start coloring. You can not color different shapes with different colors at the same compound path because it is an unique vector object. Duplicate the image before to keep the original.

Answer (score 1):

After converting any image to vector first you have to **expand** that. 
then you can able to **ungroup it**.

[image]